# Can I retract a close vote after the question is closed?

Tags: support, voting, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

I recently came across a problem that I was unable to solve.

By accident I voted to close a question. The vote was intended for a different question. It's not something that happens often, but in this case I had some separators opened, and it happened. Because it was the third vote, the question was closed.

I tried to retract the vote but I didn't find a way to do it, so I flagged the question for moderator intervention to do that for me.

The answer from the moderator was something like "Retract your vote, I can't do it for you".

The thing is I did not find any way to do it. Can anyone tell me how this is done?

How can I retract a close vote when the question is already closed ?

Comment: You'd have to vote to reopen.

Comment: @RobertLongson, yes, I eventually did that, and the question was later reopened so it was solved. The moderator answer led me to believe that the vote could still be retracted.

Comment: Related: [Can't rescind my close vote after closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364694/335251)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do so - as your close vote has now been "consumed" by the question getting closed, there is no longer a vote to retract. Your only option is to push for the post to be reopened.

As far as the decline reason, Stack Overflow has a high flag volume, a lot of which comes from users who use moderator flags in cases where they should have used votes, so moderators there tend to reflexively decline such flags to save time. The moderator in this case likely assumed so. To better increase the chances that your flag is properly handled, you should explain in detail why a moderator is required.